# Type mismatch word

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
Private Sub RunSpellCheckOnSelection()

    MsgBox "Running check..."

    Dim wbDictionaryCollection As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wsDictionary           As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim rngWords               As Excel.Range

    Set wbDictionaryCollection = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(Application.ActiveDocument.Path & "\Dictionary.xlsx")
    Set wsDictionary = wbDictionaryCollection.Worksheets(strLanguage)
    Set rngWords = wsDictionary.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Dim PUNCTUATION As String
    PUNCTUATION = ".,:;'!?/\@#$%^&*(){}[]-_=+|<>`~" & Chr(13)

    Dim blnWordFound As Boolean

    Dim nDictionaryWords As Long
    Dim iDictionaryWord As String

    Dim nWords As Long
    Dim iWord  As Long

    Dim nPunctuation As Long
    Dim iPunctuation As Long

    nDictionaryWords = rngWords.Rows.Count
    nWords = Selection.words.Count
    nPunctuation = Len(PUNCTUATION)

    ' For every word in selection:
    For iWord = 1 To nWords

            ' Check if the word is in the dictionary:
            blnWordFound = False

            For iDictionaryWord = 1 To nDictionaryWords
                    ''''''''
                    If Selection.words(iWord).Text = Mid$(rngWords.Cells(iDictionaryWord, 1), 1, Len(rngWords.Cells(iDictionaryWord, 1) - 2)) Then
```

This line provides me a type mismatch error, and I don't realise what's wrong here..

I edited and added the rest of code ! And I obtain a type mistach error on the Mid function

Comment: Impossible for anyone to offer an opion - you don't provide enough context. What's `iWord`? What's the content of `rngWords.Cells`?, What's the value of `iDictionaryWord`?

Comment: iWord is every word from my selection (Word document), the context of rngWords.Cells is to check if the word is in the dictionary (dictionary in this case, is a excel with words on it, rngWords is Excel range basically). I added the other code as well

Answer (score 0):

You have two separate syntax errors in that statement, and each of them is repeated.

First, the Cells property of a Range object returns a Cell object, not a string. That's causing the type mismatch error. To correct it, use rngWords.Cells(...).Range.Text in both places.

The first error is hiding a second error: The Cells property of a range takes a single number of type Long as its argument, but you've supplied two numbers. If you click Debug > Compile Project, it will highlight the word Cells and explain "Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment." I can't tell what you expected the ",1" to do, but it shouldn't be there.